# Auto start AndroVM on VirtualBox

Tags: android, jenkins, virtualbox, robotium, androvm

I went through the trouble of trying to start a VM when the system starts up but ran into issues of no GUI pops up so the Robotium UI testing I am doing fails.  I need to find some way to automatically start up the VirtualBox - [AndroVM](http://androvm.org/blog/) image I have using Jenkins so I can run my Robotium UI testing on it.  (side note - Oh yeah on thing is Jenkins is installed on a Mac mini so we can compile iPhone apps too.)

Comment: Maybe you really need AndroVM, but if not, you could install the HAXM extensions on your Mac (so you can use the speedy standard x86 emulator images), and use the Jenkins Android Emulator Plugin to start them. Works well for me on a Mac Mini (which is also used for iOS + Jenkins :)

Comment: The emulators are horrible and consistently throws false UI errors while running Robotium.  AndroVM is as close to a phone as it gets and runs faster and no UI errors either.

Comment: Apparently there is no answer for this.... :-(